# Changing AppName depending on User Input in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I have Custom Page in my Setup which asks User to enter Identifier. My requirement is that if user enters the Identifier then App name should be changed to include the identifier.

My setup section looks like

```
#define AppName 'SMARTsoft Name and Address Import'

[Setup]
AppName={#AppName}
```

Custom Page is created as :-

```
function CreateDataPage(PreviousPageId: Integer): Integer;
var
    Page: TWizardPage;
begin
    Page :=CreateCustomPage(PreviousPageId,'Additional Identifier for the Interface',
    'Provide any extra information/identifier you will be using');

    FirstLabel :=TLabel.Create(Page);
    with FirstLabel do
        begin
            Parent :=Page.Surface;
            Caption :='Identifier';
            Left :=ScaleX(56);
            Top :=ScaleY(36);
            Width :=ScaleX(70);
            Height :=ScaleY(17);
        end;   

    txtIndentifier :=TEdit.Create(Page);
    with txtIndentifier do
    begin
        Parent :=Page.Surface;
        Left :=ScaleX(136);
        Top :=ScaleY(36);
        Width :=ScaleX(51);
        Height :=ScaleY(25);
        TabOrder :=3;
        Text :='';
        MaxLength := 5;
    end;

    with Page do
    begin
        OnNextButtonClick :=@Check;
    end;

    Result :=Page.ID;

end;
```

Now I want to check if User has given value in control txtIndentifier then change the AppName. For which I have added function on Next Button click which is :-

```
function Check(Page: TWizardPage): Boolean;
begin
    Result :=True;
    MsgBox('In Authentication', mbError, MB_OK);          
    if txtIndentifier.Text <> ''  then
      begin
        ***<<here I want to update the App Name>>***
        ***something like - {#AppName} := ExpandConstant('{#AppName}') + ' (' + txtIndentifier.Text + ')';***

      end  
end;
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: I think this should [`give you a clue`](http://pastebin.com/GkS7DG5Q).

Comment: Thanks for your reply TLama. But when I follow the link, I get following compile time error.                                                                UsePreviousLanguage must be set to "no" when AppId includes constants

Comment: Hence I used the `AppId` directive. You must specify it because the installer would build it for you otherwise. And since the installer uses for it the `AppName` which would not be known yet, it prevents you to build the setup.

Comment: Ok so I have used AppId in my code and now it looks like   AppID=1
AppName={code:GetAppName}. But now when i run my setup file it gives me error Could not call proc

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tried that code. Well, the problem is that the `AppName` directive is evaluated at the wizard startup, so forget that code.

Comment: Yup, i just came to know that. So is there a way to change the AppName after getting user input because with the above code It tries to get the AppName value at the startup where no controls are initialized.                                                                                                   So is there a way to update the AppName after user has given the input and has pressed next button. Thanks

Comment: The `AppName` value is used for various things. Some of these might be possible to chang on runtime with some effort, some cannot. So what (functionally) is it that you really want to change? From [the documatation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appname): `AppName` is displayed throughout the Setup program and uninstaller in window titles, wizard pages, and dialog boxes.The value of this directive is also used as the default value for the `AppId`, `VersionInfoDescription`, and `VersionInfoProductName` directives if those are not specified.

Comment: I want to change the AppName, So that User input value can be added in AppName . This way user will be able to use same setup file multiple times to install the program multiple times with different AppName.